# What does function.part.10 means in GDB enviorment?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm working on a project in C++ which has a SegFault problem. The project is very big, has a lot of .hpp and classes, etc. So, I'm trying to use GDB to debug my code. When I run it in GDB terminal, the code runs until it reaches the SegFault. So, GDB returns me the following message:

```
Thread 1 "uclcl_param_est" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555556ea9bb in classExtractPerturbation.part.10 ()
```

I know what function is that, and in which class and folder is, but I was expecting to GDB tells me also the line where I have the problem. Also, when I use the command "list", GDB returns me the following message:

```
(gdb) l
1   <built-in>: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I don't know exactly how to interpret this. Could someone help to interpret this? On internet, I found GDB guides for simple codes with only one .cpp file, but in my case it has a lot of them.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to debug a release build, not a debug build. Try to remove optimizations (`-O0` in gcc) and add debug symbols to the build options (`-g` in gcc).

Comment: When in compiling? I compiled the code using `make CFLAGS=-g name_here`. Should I use `make CFLAGS=-g -O0 name_here` ?

Comment: Use a logging library like Glog or spdlog.

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting to GDB tells me also the line where I have the problem

GDB will only tell you file and line *IFF* you have compiled your code with file/line debug info. Usually this is achieved with `-g` flag (which generates full debug info), but you could also use `-gmlt` if you are only interested in file/line info (but not variables and parameters).

> What does function.part.10 means in GDB enviorment?

GDB has nothing to do with this -- the compiler emitted a symbol `classExtractPerturbation.part.10`, and GDB is just telling you that that's where the crash is.

You can read about the meaning of `.part.10` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247356).